# Develop a proof of concept data warehouse/mart (using dimensional model)

Tags: database, dimensional-modeling

I am doing CA in data storage, my teacher asked the below question but I dont know is "proof of concept data warehouse by using dimensional model)"
Could you help me explain this?

1. Data Warehouse is developed to obtain business intelligence from data. Develop a **proof of concept data warehouse**/mart (**using dimensional model**) capturing data from an existing data source(s).  Document your reasons for selecting the subject area(s), identify key stakeholders, formalise the business vision for developing the data warehouse from the given data source.  Also explain the insights that a company may attain from the given data.  It should be reflected in the reports and visuals.

Answer (score 0):

To start with:

1. Select an area of interest for analysis and find a dataset. Example: Movie dataset, crime dataset or football player statistics etc.
2. Select a particular attribute as a fact. In the example if you take an IMDb movie dataset, you can take IMDb rating as your fact and actors, movie, directors and date can be your dimensions. (For more detail about dimensional modelling refer [Dimensional modelling for datawarehouse](https://www.guru99.com/dimensional-model-data-warehouse.html#:%7E:text=DIMENSIONAL%20MODELING%20(DM)%20is%20a,%22%20and%20%22dimension%22%20tables.))
3. You have your proof of concept of analysing what factors from your dimensional tables can influence your fact table.

By developing a data warehouse using Microsoft SQL, SSMS and Tableau or any other tools, you can analyse the insights.